# Use-case of #pragma start and #pragma exit

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor, pragma

> **#pragma startup** and **#pragma exit**:  These directives helps us to specify the functions that are needed to run before program
>   startup( before the control passes to main()) and just before program
>   exit (just before the control returns from main()).

Can anyone suggest me any use-case of these preprocessor directive?

I am afraid these might have very limited use-case in Object oriented programming. Has anyone found it being used in a project?

Comment: I agree.  You could also create a static instance of an object.  The constructor will also be called before entering main and the destructor after returning from main.

Comment: I have seen (C and assembler) code being executed before main (and actually before/instead of crt), when it does things which cannot wait for the (sometimes lengthy) activities of crt. However, "there be dragons".

Comment: This appears to be taken from a blog by Karthik Byggari. I would disregard him; the fact he's still talking about the 20th century "Turbo C" compiler shows how much relevance this has today.

Comment: Which compiler is it that supports these pragmas? I've never heard of them before. Can you give a source for this quotation, and maybe provide some context?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-preprocessors/

Comment: Well, in that article, where it talks about `#pragma start` and `#pragma exit`, it has a button that says "Run In IDE", but when I click on that, those directives obviously don't do anything. They're ignored by the compiler. Which suggests that this person is either (A) talking nonsense, or (B) talking about a very non-standard compiler that he doesn't bother to name.

Answer (score 2):

The most important part about these directives is the ability to assign priorities for functions to be called before/after main. This comes in handy to overcome ["static initialization order fiasco"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).
The answer to your second question: no, I haven't seen these directives being used in real-world applications.

Comment: Would a `#pragma start` directive *really* solve this problem? It seems like it would just kick the can further down the street. Furthermore, it seems doubtful to me that `#pragma start` actually runs the code *before* initializing global statics. But I can't find any compiler that supports these, so I can't find any documentation on them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid giving (even partial) answers in a comment, I contribute this view point:

I have seen (C and assembler) code in realtime systems, being executed before main (and actually before/instead of crt), when it does things which cannot wait for the (sometimes lengthy) activities of crt. However, "there be dragons".